# Anybody know what/where the error is in this code?

Tags: beamer, errors

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{.125,.5,.25}
%\usecolortheme[named=mygreen]{structure}
\title{Continuity, Differentiability, and Derivatives}
\author{dsdf}
\date{\today}
\setbeamercovered{transparent = 15}
\begin{document}
\metroset{block=fill}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Continuity}

A function is continuous if it can be drawn without picking up the pencil; otherwise, it is discontinuous. Function f(x) is continuous if:
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
\vspace{5pt}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\vspace{10pt}
\item $f(a)$ exists
\item $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$=$f(a)$
\item $\lim\limits_{x \to a^{+}} f(x)$=$\lim\limits_{x \to a^{-}} f(x)$
\end{enumerate}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Continuity}
A function is differentiable at a point \textit{c} if $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$ exists. In other words, the slope must:
\only<1>{\line(1,0){50}\,}
\only<2,3,4>{\textcolor{magenta}{exist}}.
\\
\vspace{30pt}
If a function is 
\only<1,2>{\line(1,0){50}\,} 
\only<3,4>{\textcolor{magenta}{differentiable}}
it must also be 
\only<1,2,3>{\line(1,0){50}\,}
\only<4>{\textcolor{magenta}{continuous}}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Types of Discontinuity}
\only<1>{\begin{block}{Removable Discontinuity} 
\vspace{4pt}
$\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f(x) =\lim\limits_{x \to a^-} f(x)$, but $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f(x) \neq f(a)$ 
\vspace{4pt}
\end{block} 
\vspace{8pt}
\vspace{10pt}
\only<2>{\begin{block}{Jump Discontinuity}
\vspace{4pt}
$\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f(x) \neq \lim\limits_{x \to a^-} f(x)$
\vspace{4pt}
\end{block}
\vspace{10pt}
\only<3>{\begin{block} {Infinite Discontinuity}
\vspace{4pt}
$\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \infty$ and/or $\lim\limits_{x \to a^-} f(x) = \infty$
\vspace{4pt}
\end{block}
\vspace{10pt}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Derivatives}
\begin{block}{Definition of the Derivative}
\vspace{4pt}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\column{0.5\textwidth}
$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$
\column{0.5\textwidth}
$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = f'(x)$
\end{columns}
\vspace{4pt}
\end{block}
Set D is called the
\only<1>{\line(1,0){50}\, }
\only<2>{\textcolor{magenta}{domain}}
of the function.\\[10pt]
Set E is called the
\only<1>{\line(1,0){50}\, }
\only<2>{\textcolor{magenta}{range}}
of the function.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Derivative of an Inverse}
\only <1> [$f^{-1}$]'(b) = 
\only <1> $\displaystyle\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(b))}$
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Exampe of Inverse Derivatives}
\only <1,2,3>
\only <2,3>
\only <1,2,3>
\only <3>
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Implicit Differentiation}
Use implicit differentiation to find the derivative of $xy=1$
\vspace{8pt}
\\Step 1: $\frac{d}{dx}(xy)=\frac{d}{dx}(1)$
\vspace{8pt}
\\Step 2: $(y+x(\frac{dy}{dx}))=0$
\vspace{8pt}
\\Step 3: $x(\frac{dy}{dx})=-y$
\vspace{8pt}
\\Step 4: $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x}$
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Trig Derivatives}
\begin{block}{Trig Derivatives}
\vspace{8pt}
\begin{columns}
\column{.3\textwidth}
$[sin(x)]'=$
\only<2-7>{$cos(x)$}
\\$[cos(x)]'=$
\only<3-7>{$-sin(x)$}
\\$[tan(x)]'=$
\only<4-7>{$sec^2(x)$}
\column{.4\textwidth}
$[cot(x)]'=$
\only<5-7>{$-csc^2(x)$}
\\$[sec(x)]'=$
\only<6-7>{$sec(x) tan(x)$}
\\$[csc(x)]'=$
\only<7>{$-csc(x) cot(x)$}
\end{columns}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Inverse Trig Derivatives}
\begin{block}{Inverse Trig Derivatives}
$[sin^{-1}(x)]'=$
\only<2-4>{$\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$}
\\$[tan^{-1}(x)]'=$
\only<3-4>{$\displaystyle{\frac{1}{x^2+1}}$}
\\$[sec^{-1}(x)]'=$
\only<4>{$\displaystyle{\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}}$}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Exponential and Logarithmic Derivatives}
Some of the rules for exponential and logarithmic derivatives are:
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\displaystyle [e^u]' = \displaystyle u' \cdot e^u$
\item $\displaystyle [b^u]' = \displaystyle ln(b) \cdot b^u$, where \textit{b} is a constant.
\item $\displaystyle[ln\; u]' = \displaystyle \frac{1}{u}$
\end{enumerate}
Find the derivatives for these examples:
\begin{enumerate}
\item $e^{2x}$
\item $2^x$
\item $ln\; 3$
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: We don't like big code dumps that make us do all the work.  What error message does TeX give you?  Comment out a bunch of stuff.  Is the error still there?  Repeat until you've found the minimal amount of code that still produces the error.  If you still don't understand why the error is happening at that point, then we'll be happy to help.

Comment: You aren't closing the argument to `\only` in the frame “Types of Discontinuity”.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to three missing braces closing the argument to `\only`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for only is like `\only<1>{...}`, but you have forgotten the closing brace in the three `only`s in the frame you get errors for, i.e. the *Types of discontinuity* frame. Add an `}` after each `\end{block}` in that frame.

You also have one frame where you have just four `\only<..>`, with no braces at all, and those cause errors as well. Add the brace pair.